# React Native onChangeText like onChange in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I learn in the same time ReactJS and React Native. I saw in an udemy tutorial something very beautiful, that the professor putt it just one onChange method, for all inputs and taking advantage of the "name" attribute, he could do this:

```
const onChange = event =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
```

So he said, instead of having for each onChange, inside of each input, a different method, we can have only one.

This is the code that I'm talking about:

```
const Register = props => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    password2: ''
  });

  const { name, email, password, password2 } = formData;
  const onChange = event =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });

  const onSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (password !== password2) {
      props.setAlert('Passwords do not match', 'danger', 5000);
    } else {
      props.registerUser({ name, email, password });
    }
  };


  if (props.isAuthenticated) {
    return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
  }
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="large text-primary">Sign Up</h1>
      <p className="lead">
        <i className="fas fa-user" /> Create Your Account
      </p>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={event => onSubmit(event)}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name"
            name="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={event => onChange(event)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email Address"
            name="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={event => onChange(event)}
          />
          <small className="form-text">
            This site uses Gravatar so if you want a profile image, use a
            Gravatar email
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            name="password"
            // minLength="6"
            value={password}
            onChange={event => onChange(event)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Confirm Password"
            name="password2"
            value={password2}
            onChange={event => onChange(event)}
          />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />
      </form>
      <p className="my-1">
        Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Sign In</Link>
      </p>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

In React Native, that is with a different professor, I tried to think how to do this. I tried a few days the offered props from the TextInput but non of then, in my opinion, can be used how we can use the "name" attribute in ReactJS.

This is the code for the React Native app:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Button,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

class PlaceInput extends Component {
  state = {
    userName: '',
    placeName: ''
  }

  userNameChangeHandler = (value) => {
    this.setState({ userName: value })
  }

  placeNameChangeHandler = (value) => {
    this.setState({ placeName: value })
  }

  placeSubmitHandler = () => {
    if (this.state.placeName.trim() === '') {
      return;
    }

    this.props.onPlaceAdded(this.state.placeName)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.placeInput}
          value={this.state.userName}
          onChangeText={this.userNameChangeHandler}
          placeholder='User Name' />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.placeInput}
          value={this.state.placeName}
          onChangeText={this.placeNameChangeHandler}
          placeholder='Beautiful place' />
        <Button title='Add' style={styles.placeButton} onPress={this.placeSubmitHandler} />
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

Please someone help me to understand: it is possible to have one onChangeText method in React Native, like the professor from ReactJS did with onChange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing input "name" as a value to the handler function.
Like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet, View, TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

class PlaceInput extends Component {
  state = {
    userName: '',
    placeName: ''
  }

  handleInputChange = (inputName, inputValue) => {
    this.setState(state => ({ 
      ...state,
      [inputName]: inputValue // <-- Put square brackets
    }))
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.placeInput}
          value={this.state.userName}
          onChangeText={value => this.handleInputChange('userName', value)}
          placeholder='User Name' />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.placeInput}
          value={this.state.placeName}
          onChangeText={value => this.handleInputChange('placeName', value)}
          placeholder='Beautiful place' />
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: You're very welcome. BTW check the updated code. It should be `event.nativeEvent` and not `event.target` in React-Native

Comment: do I do something wrong or you missed something, because I get a little error when I start typing in the inputs: 
``undefined is not an object evaluating event.nativeEvent.name``

Comment: Can you check the line number you are getting that error at?

Comment: the error was: ```This error is located at:
    in PlaceInput (at basicsReactNative/index.js:12)
    in Provider (at basicsReactNative/index.js:11)
    in RNRedux (at renderApplication.js:40)
    in RCTView (at View.js:35)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:35)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)``` and in index.js at line 12 I have inported this PlaceInput.js component that I renamed App

Comment: I guess you forgot to change "onChange" to "onChangeText"

Comment: For the first time when I got undefined(In the above error, from my prev comment), indeed I had still onChangeText, but after I put onChage, I got : ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null```.

Comment: Can you copy-paste your whole PlaceInput class here:
http://collabedit.com/p74ey
I'll check your code.

Comment: You are still using `onChange`. Change it to `onChangeText` and it will work. :)

Comment: I had a typo, but still I can't type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198043/discussion-between-utkarshpramodgupta-and-dragon).

Comment: what about `hanldeInputChange = (name) => e => { ... }`, would that be better?

Answer (score 1):

For that type of a function you are using the wrong prop. While `onChangeText` is all fine, it takes as its parameter a function with a single parameter: the changed text. Because of that you cannot do it with the `onChangeText`.

However, there exists another prop called `onChange`. This one supplies the following object as the parameter per the documentation: `{ nativeEvent: { eventCount, target, text} }`. Target here, while could be used, is going to be just a number.

What would I suggest?

Instead of trying to handle it through the `event.target.name` change your function to take a second argument: `name`. After that you should call your functions as follows;

`onChangeText={text => this.inputChangeHandler(text, 'name')}`

This will create a function whose sole purpose is to supply the second parameter, allowing you to use just one function for all your text changes.